# My OS project's API looks similar to another one

Tags: license

I've been experimenting with databases.

I like the idea of Collection-Document relationships.

My project looks like this:

```
const client = new Client("localhost", 8080, "project")

const City = client.createCollection("city", {
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  index: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  visited: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

await client.connect();

const cities = await City.query().find({ index: { $gt: 1 } }).fetch();
```

If I wanted to write a similar code for MongoDB, we would have:

```
const client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

await client.connect();

const db = client.db("project");

const collection = db.collection("city");

const cities = await collection.find({ index: { $gt: 1 } })
```

Sorry for comparing both projects, I have to do it so you can give me a better explanation.

As you can see, there are some differences, for example, my project accepts a `Collection` schema.

The thing I'm worried about is that the `find` argument is very similar in both cases.

My project will also accept things like:

```
.find({ $or: [{ index: { $gt: 1 } }, { index: { $lt: 3 } }]
```

... which is also really similar to MongoDB.

Can I get into trouble because of this?

I'd like to clarify that I use no code from MongoDB. Everything is written from scratch, from client to server. My project is an independent database.

Comment: So the only similarity is that you both wrote `{ index: { $gt: 1 } }` in the find argument? Isn't this a bit like worrying that other programmers are writing `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` in their C code? I'm not familiar with the above code, but sometimes common idioms emerge in programming languages and programming environments. Reusing a common idiom does not mean you are copying code.

Comment: @Brandin Hi, the thing is that the `$gt` syntax is created by the developer, so I wanted to make sure that I wasn't just plagiarizing other people's ideas. But I totally get your point. This is a common idiom and I should not worry about using it. Thanks.

Comment: So does that mean that in order to use the `$gt` syntax, that you have to include in some third-party support code or a third-party library? Whether or not you have to include external libraries or not to support the code you're writing will affect the correct Answer to this.

Comment: @Brandin Hi. Not at all. Everything is written from scratch. It's better this way so I can implement my own ideas to the project. While the final API may look similar to other projects, the internal implementation is different.

Comment: It should probably be mentioned in your Question and/or Answer. I'm not familiar with this programming environment or language. But many languages use 'gt' as a common abbreviation of "greater than". The fact that you named it that is certainly not original, but if there is specific code behind that implementation of checking whether something is "greater than" something else, then of course that specific code is probably protectable as an original work with licensing considerations.

Comment: @Brandin As you can see, the `find` method accepts a JSON object. A JSON object will represent a schema and that's it; it's up to the project to use that schema to perform comparisons, so yeah, there's an internal implementation for checking if something is "greater than" something else. The way I see it is that I'm getting inspiration from the MongoDB syntax but I'm not actually copying the source code (I'm also implementing other ideas that are not present on the MongoDB solution). What do you think about this?

Comment: So if I'm looking at this again, it seems like your above JSON object is just a rephrashing of what I would normally write in a C-like language as the logical statement `index > 1 OR index < 3`. Btw, this seems like a bit of a logic error (a tautology), since it would accept an index of all values. Perhaps you instead meant `index > 1 AND index < 3`. If index is an integer, then it seems it could also be simplied to `.find({ index: { $eq: 2 }})` if I'm using your above notation.

Comment: @Brandin Hi, I was just showing an example of the syntax. I didn't think much about the result. Now I know it would get just any number, haha. Thank you for following up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In programming and in copyright law, ideas and conventions are not protectible by copyright. Oftentimes, an existing convention will be in place in a particular domain, and it is prudent to reuse that convention in the interest of making your code more understandable to others. So, in general, if you are "copying" a convention (without copying source code) then in general that does not require a copyright license.

In the system you have described, it appears you have the technical problem of trying to express a logical statement that would traditionally be written like this:

```
(index > 1) ∧ (index < 3)
```

And that you have a technical solution for this to write it in a JSON-friendly manner, by translating it as follows (since I don't think symbols like ">", "&&", "||", etc. are allowed to be used as key names in JSON):

```
{$and: [{index: { $gt: 1 }}, {index: { $lt: 3 }}]}
```

Roughly speaking, this idea, this particular convention, and/or the technical solution itself are not protectible by copyright law, but any *creative expressions* using this solution would be. For example, if you were to write a technical document in which you described all of the different possible operators in your convention ($eq, $ne, $gt, $ge, $lt, $le, $and, $or, $not, etc.), then such a specification document itself would probably count as a creative expression and would therefore receive copyright protection, just like any other technical documentation gets copyright protection.

With a quick Internet search I also found a non-open source product (IBM Db2) which supports the above syntax as well (or something that looks very much like it):

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=queries-logical-operators

So, those technical documents themselves are protected by copyright, as is the actual software (Db2) but the fact that IBM used the same symbols as you ($and, $or, etc.) should not be a copyright concern. The only possible risk to open source might be if a company or individual tried to patent such a scheme, but that seems pretty unlikely in this case.

I've heard some people advocate that to properly write your own code free of license concerns, that you must not allow yourself to be "contaminated" by looking at other implementations, but for this case, since what you are writing is basically a user interface for other programmers, then I would personally advocate looking at the available documentation from IBM and others (CouchDB, etc.) and consider supporting some of the same features as well in your version if they seem useful (such as $in, $nin, $regex, which seem pretty convenient as well as self-explanatory). Also take a look at IBM's version of the "$and" JSON logical operator, since the way they specified it in Db2 seems like it would lead to a cleaner and easier-to-use syntax. Just be sure to "copy" only the convention (such as allowing $regex to specify a regular expression) but to write the underlying code yourself.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for the thorough answer. My gut was telling me that it was ok to use that syntax, but I wasn't really sure. It's better to ask. Sorry for bringing up this topic about conventions. While I was waiting for someone to give me the green light, I've been coding the `$in`, `$regex`, etc. support, so it's really cool. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I've been doing my research, and the syntax I'm talking about is used in projects other than MongoDB.

- In [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/) they have [Mango queries](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/tour.html#running-a-mango-query).
- In [Cloudant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant) they have [Cloudant queries](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-creating-an-ibm-cloudant-query).
- In [RxDB](https://rxdb.info/) they have [RxQuery](https://rxdb.info/rx-query.html).

So it's safe to assume that I should not worry too much about using the same syntax.

Comment: Your conclusion is probably correct based on my understanding, but your reasoning is not that good. Just because some other projects are doing a certain thing with some source code, does not necessarily mean it's allowed or is open-source compatible. The thing that you're proposing to do almost certainly should be allowed or should not be allowed, regardless of whether or not others are doing the same.

Comment: Or to put Brandin's comment another way: I was driving down the motorway and I saw many people breaking the speed limit. That doesn't mean it's legal to speed.

Comment: @Brandin I get it. My concern was if I was going to get into trouble for using that syntax, but since other projects are using it with no problem, it's a relief. You're right though. I should be careful about doing the right thing regardless of what other peeps are doing.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Good analogy! Thanks.